# Identify my old motorbike

Tags: part-identification

My old motorbike part, I want help to identify please.

[image: old motorbike part]

Answer (score 14):

BrickLink calls it a [Fabuland Scooter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=fabac3). In white, it seems to have been in [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=fabac3&in=S).

[image: BrickSet 3789]

[image: BrickSet 3794]

Comment: Thanks RSchulz
for your help !!!

Comment: @Georgios If RSchulz answered your question, you should accept their answer with the check mark to the left.